# Subset rows of multiple data frames based on variable values on two columns

Tags: linux, shell

I have multiple data frames which look like this:

df1

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;1;2;blue
house;1;2;red
dog;5;6;yellow
mouse;7;8;white
```

df2

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;3;4;grey
house;7;8;red
dog;5;6;yellow
mouse;3;4;black
```

df3

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;5;6;grey
house;3;4;red
dog;5;6;yellow
mouse;9;10;grey
```

I would like to subset all the rows where the values of col2 and col3 are equal to the value of col2 and col3 of "cat" 
The values of col2 and col3 keep changing in each data frame so are not constant.
The output would be :

df1

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;1;2;blue
house;1;2;red
```

df2

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;3;4;grey
mouse;3;4;black
```

df3

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
cat;5;6;grey
dog;5;6;yellow
```

Any suggestion?
Indeed I can use all the time awk:

```
awk -F";" '{if($2=="1" && $3=="2")print $0}' df1 
awk -F";" '{if($2=="3" && $3=="4")print $0}' df2
awk -F";" '{if($2=="5" && $3=="6")print $0}' df3
```

but I have thousands of data frames so it is troublesome to manually input the values for each line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
awk -F\; '                              # set field separator
FNR == 1        {D1 = D2 = ""           # on new file (= line No. 1), reset variables
                 FN = FILENAME "_tmp"   # compose new filename
                 print > FN             # print header line to new file
                }
/^cat/          {D2 = $2                # if found "cat", set variables D2 and 
                 D3 = $3                # D3
                }
$2 == D2 &&                             # if fields $2 and $3 match variables, i.e. $2 and $3 from "cat" line
$3 == D3        {print > FN             # print line to new file
                }
' df*                                   # work on every "df*" file in sight
```

Then `mv` the *tmp file over the original ones...

Comment: please, can you explain it a bit? because I can't adapt it to my data frames

Comment: @Paolo Lorenzini: Added comments for more clarity. I can't see difficulties to adapt unless "data frames" are something far from *nix files.